# Using Promise.all() with SequeliseJS

Tags: node.js, promise

I'd like to check if uploading files are used in my database. So I'd like to list all files in the "uploads" folder and then check with SequelizeJs if item are finded with the right property.

My code seems not working as espected :

```
var promises = [];

fs.readdir('./public/uploads', (err, files) => {
  if (!err) {

    promises = files.filter(function(file) {
      if (file !== 'csv' && file !== '.gitignore') {

        // vérification dans FileModel
        return models.FileModel.findOne({ where: { name: '/uploads/' + file } }).then(function(findedFile) {
          if (!findedFile) {
            return Promise.resolve(file).then(function() {

              // Vérification dans VehiclePhotoModel
              return models.VehiclePhotoModel.findOne({ where: { name: '/uploads/' + file } }).then(function(findedFile) {
                if (!findedFile) {
                  return Promise.resolve(file);
                }
              });
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});

Promise.all(promises).then(function(unusedFiles) {
  response.render('file/_checkUnusedFiles', {
    _layoutFile: false,
    unusedFiles: unusedFiles
  });
});
```

**Edit #1 :**

I've mixed up your code that doesn't work for me but I still get an issue, the Promise.resolve() is not returning the string name file.

```
const fileModels = [
  { model: models.FileModel, property: 'name' },
  { model: models.VehiclePhotoModel, property: 'name' }
];

function _checkUnusedFiles(request, response) {
  var promises = [],
      files = _.remove(fs.readdirSync('./public/uploads'), function(file) {
        return file !== 'csv' && file !== '.gitignore';
      });

  promises = _.map(files, function(file) {
    return fileModels.map(function(fileModel) {
      var where = {};
      where[fileModel.property] = file;
      return fileModel.model.findOne({ where: where }).then(function(findedItem) {
        if (!findedItem) {
          return Promise.resolve(file);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then(function(unusedFiles) {
    response.render('optimizer/_checkUnusedFiles', {
      _layoutFile: false,
      unusedFiles: unusedFiles
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Let me understand this, so you are trying to filter the files to those that exist in db either in `FileModel` or in `VehiclePhotoModel` and you care about that specific order check in `FileModel` first and then `VehiclePhotoModel`? and you want to know the names of those files that dont exist?

Comment: Yes exactly, I just need to check if files exists in the DB and I want to returns the file name that is used in the folder.

Comment: Got it. Please check my answer, it should solve your issue. It is not the best out there but it will get your job done just fine.

Comment: Can't see that the order of the findOne query pairs should matter. They could be done in parallel, surely. And the solution becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0):

With the above code soon you get into callback hell, which will result in issues like the ones you have mentioned. Anyways, so the problem is as follows

`files.filter` returns

> <string[]> | <Buffer[]> | <fs.Dirent[]>

taken from documentation:https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback

a better approach would be to loop and then do something like `promises.append(...)`

even better approach break down your code using `async` `await` to avoid callback hell and issues like this

You really don't need `Promise.all` in your case as it might complicated things even further and could be a performance bottleneck.

Something like this should work fine

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

// Mocking SequeliseJS (You can remove this and replace in code as well with original models
const modelsMock = {
  FileModel: {
    findOne: (query) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // rand will just randomize result between true and false
        let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(2))
        resolve(rand == 1 ? resolve(true) : resolve(false))
      })
    }
  },

  VehiclePhotoModel: {
    findOne: (query) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // rand will just randomize result between true and false
        let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(2))
        resolve(rand == 1 ? resolve(true) : resolve(false))
      })
    }
  }  
}

run()

async function run() {
  let promises = []
  let existFiles = []
  let doesntExistFiles = []

  // If the goal is to use readdir async then uncomment the following and comment let files = fs.readdirSync('./public/uploads')
  /* 
  const util = require('util')
  const readdir = util.promisify(fs.readdir);
  let files = await readdir('./public/uploads')
  */

  let files = fs.readdirSync('./public/uploads')
  
  // Filter files: (using array.filter is pretty useless to us here since we can't run it async unless we want to promisify it which there are plenty of examples out there, for now we will stick with good old fashion loop)

  for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const file = files[i]
    if(path.extname(file) !== '.csv' && path.extname(file) !== '.gitignore') {
      try {
         let exist = await checkIfFileExist(file, modelsMock)
         exist === true ? existFiles.push(file) : doesntExistFiles.push(file)
      } catch (e) {
         // Handle error here
      }
    }
  }
  
  response.render('file/_checkUnusedFiles', {
      _layoutFile: false,
      unusedFiles: unusedFiles //Note this will break the code as unusedFiles is undefined, I really dont know what is this variable hence I didn't change it but feel free to change it as you see it appropriate.
  });
}

async function checkIfFileExist(file, models){
  let query = `{ where: { name: '/uploads/' + ${file} } }`
  
    try {
       let existInFiles = await models.FileModel.findOne(query)
       if(!existInFiles) {
          let existInVehicle = await models.VehiclePhotoModel.findOne(query)
          existInVehicle ? return true : return false
       } else {
          return true
       }
    }
    catch(e) {
       throw e
    }
  
}
```

here is the full example working on `Repl.it`

https://repl.it/repls/DramaticAwfulSpreadsheets#index.js

**EDIT1:**

Like I mentioned in the comments I don't really suggest what you are doing (My opinion at least :)); however, if you flatten your array everything should be fine.

```
const fileModels = [
  { model: models.FileModel, property: 'name' },
  { model: models.VehiclePhotoModel, property: 'name' }
];

function _checkUnusedFiles(request, response) {
  var promises = [],
      files = _.remove(fs.readdirSync('./public/uploads'), function(file) {
        // I think you want to check for extension here and not the file name? if so use this
       // return (path.extname(file) !== '.csv' && path.extname(file) !== '.gitignore') //Make sure to require('path')
        return file !== 'csv' && file !== '.gitignore';
      });

  promises = _.map(files, function(file) {
    return fileModels.map(function(fileModel) {
      var where = {};
      // Your query seems wrong? at least different from last time. If it is intentional then you are good otherwise I think you meant to do
      //  where[fileModel.property] = `/uploads/${file}`
      where[fileModel.property] = file;

 
      return fileModel.model.findOne({ where: where }).then(function(findedItem) {
        if (!findedItem) {
          return Promise.resolve(file);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  // Your promises array is more like a 2d array because each file will map to an array of 2 promises 
  // So if you flatten it, you should get a 1D promises array
  promises = promises.flat()

  Promise.all(promises).then(function(unusedFiles) {
    response.render('optimizer/_checkUnusedFiles', {
      _layoutFile: false,
      unusedFiles: unusedFiles
    });
  });
}
```

If you don't flatten the output of `promises` looks something like the following

```
promises = 
[
  [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ],
  [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]
]
```

Each entry is a `file` which has 2 promises for each `model`

So when you do `Promise.all(promises)` it really doesn't know how interpret that in 2D arrays; However, when you flatten it, your output looks something similar to:

```
promises = 
[
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> }
]
```

Now keep in mind `unusedFiles` output may look weird and that is because not every promise will actually resolve to something meaningful, at least that is what you are mapping.

Comment: Your code does not work for me, I juste posted an edit of my code with your inspiration. Can you see the issue in my code with `Promise.resolve()` ?

Comment: Doing an async function inside the promise constructor is dangerous error-handling wise and is also pointless in terms of accomplishing anything. It can just be a `return existInVehicle`. Also you probably have a string query by mistake there?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum 100% correct. That's why I was catching it with `try catch` but you are right, it doesn't serve any purpose here, not sure what was I thinking. Will edit the answer. And yes that query was supposed to concatenate not use a string. Thanks for pointing them out!

Comment: @tonymx227 I will take a look at your edits and get back to you. In the mean time I have updated my answer

Comment: @tonymx227 based on what I see is that you are mapping 2 promises per file which will make your `promises` array to not really have promises but instead it will be an array with each value being an array of 2 promises, hence `Promise.all(promises)` wont do anything. I will fix your issue and edit my code; However, I dont think its a good practice to run your query twice when you are 100% sure it will be in either one. It is better to check and then recheck. Please check my updated answer.